# How to restore MySQL dump to higher version (5.7) of MySQL from lower version (5.5)

Tags: mysql

We are using OrangeHRM 3.1.1 with MySQL 5.5 version and now I need to upgrade to OrangeHRM 4.0 version with MySQL 5.7. After MySQL dump restore (I used command to restore `"mysql -u root -p newdatabase name < dump.sql"`) after restoring database am not able to login (validate credential error in browser (web/index.php/auth/validateCredentials).

Can anybody give some inputs how to restore MySQL dump from lower version to higher version

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

All higher versions support previous ones. So, you can use mysqldump 5.5 for 5.7.

I think you should look at mysqldump options, some of them were added in 5.5, some in 5.7; but the major of options work for all versions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysqldump with triggers and routines flags. Since OrangeHRM has set of triggers and routines.

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --triggers --routines databaseName > database.sql
```

Then source source it

```
mysql -u root -p newDatabaseName < database.sql
```